# Cannot import scss module styles the same way with Storybook and Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, gatsby, storybook

When I run start storybook, and import styles as such:
`import styles from './styles.module.scss'`
My styles load correctly, however when I import them like this:
`import * as styles from './styles.module.scss'`
They do not work, and I need to import them the second method because Gatsby only allows imports using the second method (to my knowledge)

```
//.storybook/main.js

const path = require('path')
const postcssConfig = require('../postcss.config')

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.story.mdx', '../src/**/*.story.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  staticDirs: ['../public'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    'storybook-addon-gatsby',
    {
      name: '@storybook/preset-scss',
      options: {
        styleLoaderOptions: {
          esModule: true,
        },
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          esModule: true,
        },
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          implementation: require('postcss'),
          postcssOptions: {
            plugins: postcssConfig,
          },
        },
        sassLoaderOptions: {
          sassOptions: {
            includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, '../src/styles')],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    // Transpile Gatsby module because Gatsby includes un-transpiled ES6 code.
    config.module.rules[0].exclude = [/node_modules\/(?!(gatsby)\/)/]
    // use @babel/preset-react for JSX and env (instead of staged presets)
    config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.presets = [
      require.resolve('@babel/preset-react'),
      require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'),
    ]
    config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.plugins = [
      // use @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties for class arrow functions
      require.resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'),
      // use babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries to remove static queries from components when rendering in storybook
      require.resolve('babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries'),
    ]

    // Prefer Gatsby ES6 entrypoint (module) over commonjs (main) entrypoint
    config.resolve.mainFields = ['browser', 'module', 'main']

    return config
  },
}


// gatsby-config.js

const contentfulConfig = {
  spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
  accessToken:
    process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN ||
    process.env.CONTENTFUL_DELIVERY_TOKEN,
}

if (process.env.CONTENTFUL_HOST) {
  contentfulConfig.host = process.env.CONTENTFUL_HOST
  contentfulConfig.accessToken = process.env.CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_ACCESS_TOKEN
}

const { spaceId, accessToken } = contentfulConfig

if (!spaceId || !accessToken) {
  throw new Error(
    'Contentful spaceId and the access token need to be provided.'
  )
}

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Gatsby Contentful Starter',
    description: 'Official Contentful Gatsby Starter',
  },
  pathPrefix: '/gatsby-contentful-starter',
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-transformer-remark',
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-image',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-contentful',
      options: contentfulConfig,
    },
  ],
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "gatsby": "^4.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-css-modules": "^4.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^5.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^5.10.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.0.0",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^6.1.4",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^5.0.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.6",
    "postcss-normalize": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss-scss": "^4.0.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "storybook-addon-gatsby": "^0.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.16.11",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.9",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.4",
    "contentful-import": "^7.8.6",
    "netlify-cli": "^2.54.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "postcss-url": "^10.1.3",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what's wrong with my config?

I've tried other config options, like adding the below syntax to my storybook main.js, but it always returns with errors

```
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
        options: {
          esModule: true,
          modules: {
            namedExport: true
          }
        }
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
          esModule: true,
          modules: {
            namedExport: true
          }
        },
      },
      require.resolve('sass-loader')
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this up for anyone who happens to run into this issue in the future. I ended up finding this answer: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/30191

But in order for it to work I needed to downgrade to webpack 4 for storybook, and downgrade a few packages as well.

```html
"css-loader": "5.2.7",
"style-loader": "2.0.0",
"sass-loader": "10.1.1",
```

here is my final .storybook/main.js

```html
const path = require('path')
const postcssConfig = require('../postcss.config')

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.story.mdx', '../src/**/*.story.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  staticDirs: ['../public'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    'storybook-addon-gatsby',
    '@storybook/addon-postcss',
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    // Transpile Gatsby module because Gatsby includes un-transpiled ES6 code.
    config.module.rules[0].exclude = [/node_modules\/(?!(gatsby)\/)/]
    // use @babel/preset-react for JSX and env (instead of staged presets)
    config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.presets = [
      require.resolve('@babel/preset-react'),
      require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'),
    ]
    config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.plugins = [
      // use @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties for class arrow functions
      require.resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'),
      // use babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries to remove static queries from components when rendering in storybook
      require.resolve('babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries'),
    ]

    // Prefer Gatsby ES6 entrypoint (module) over commonjs (main) entrypoint
    config.resolve.mainFields = ['browser', 'module', 'main']

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: [
        {
          loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
          options: {
            esModule: true,
            modules: {
              namedExport: true,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            esModule: true,
            modules: {
              namedExport: true,
            },
          },
        },
        require.resolve('sass-loader'),
      ],
    })

    return config
  },
}
```

Now `import * as styles from './styles.module.scss'` works for both Gatsby and storybook.